# IndexOutOfBoundsException when list.remove run in 2 thread the same time(concurrently)

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrency, synchronization

I have one list in main method and i want to write two thread for using this list. Sometimes i catch IndexOutOfBoundsException in synchronized block(when thread calls remove method).

Main method:

```
public class PC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        new Costumer("c1", strings).start();
        new Costumer("c2", strings).start();
        new Producer("p1", strings).start();
        new Producer("p2", strings).start();
        new Producer("p3", strings).start();
        new Producer("p4", strings).start();
    }
}
```

Costumer class:

```
class Costumer extends Thread {

    List<String> strings;
    public Costumer(String n, List<String> strings) {
        super(n);
        this.strings = strings;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (strings) {
                try {
                    if (strings.isEmpty()) {
                        strings.wait();
                    }
                    strings.remove(0); // <- where exception is thrown
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Producer class:

```
class Producer extends Thread {

    List<String> strings;

    public Producer(String n, List<String> strings) {
        super(n);
        this.strings = strings;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (strings) {
                strings.add(String.valueOf(Math.random() * 1000));
                if (strings.size() == 1) {
                    strings.notify();
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "c2" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(Unknown Source)
        at Costumer.run(PC.java:40)
```

Comment: That's definitely not the error you get with this code. What do you think `Arrays.asList` returns? Did you read its javadoc?

Comment: Also i have another thread to produce string and put them in list. I summarized it. in main code i have new Arraylist.

Comment: That's why you're supposed to test your own code if it really reproduces the problem. Btw: I don't think that this code can reproduce the problem, even after you've fixed your list initialization. So, also post the code which notifies your threads (since this may also refill that list).

Comment: when producer add string to the empty list, i call notify method.

Comment: I still don't think that this problem is reproducable with your code. If you have one producer, then it will notify a single customer and this won't cause any problem. So can you create a [mcve], please?

Comment: @Tom I edited my question and added the Complete source.

Comment: I voted to reopen because the described issue is reproducible with the code currently posted, I added the stacktrace I received to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is the if test in your `Costumer` class it must be replaced with a while loop otherwise you can face race condition issues. Indeed let's say that we have one consumer waiting to be notified, we have one consumer waiting for the lock on strings and we have the producer that has the lock on strings and that adds a new string and calls notify as we had no more string. So once it will release the lock, let's say that the consumer waiting for the lock gets it first (yes don't forget that the consumer that has been notified still needs to acquire the lock and could not necessary get the lock first), it then removes a String, then the second consumer (the one that has been notified by the consumer) will start from `strings.wait()` and will call `strings.remove(0)` without checking if it is empty or not then you will get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

In other words the code should be this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (strings) {
            try {
                while (strings.isEmpty()) {
                    strings.wait();
                }
                strings.remove(0);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway it is a good practice to wrap your condition into a while loop to avoid weird bug like this one. You can check how it is done in a class like [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java#279) for example, all conditions are checked in a while loop.

Comment: *"they will both remove the first string"* And why do you think that? Because you think that OP uses more than one producer?

Comment: why? i don't understand. Just one thread wake up in notify. Notify docs: "Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor."

Comment: @mohammad_1m2 it is a race condition issue we could have several cases. Here is one: We have one consumer waiting to be notified, we have one consumer waiting for the lock on strings and we have the producer that has the lock on strings and that adds a new string and calls notify as we had no more string. So once it will release the lock, let's say that the consumer waiting for the lock gets it first, it then removes a String, then the second consumer that has been notified will start from  strings.wait(); and will call strings.remove(0); without checking if it is empty or not => .IOOBE

Comment: @mohammad_1m2 simply try it and tell me if it worked

Comment: @Tom see my comment above about the race condition issue

Comment: @mohammad_1m2 So did you try it? I made this change on my side and I don't reproduce the bug. Please tell me what you get on your side?

Comment: *"then the second consumer that has been notified"* There won't be a second consumer notification, when the producer doesn't add another item to the list (the second item). (again, I'm thinking about the 1 producer case)

Comment: It's work fine. but i don't understand why it's correct. I Expect notifyAll wake up all threads and notify wake up the first thread. is it TRUE? Thanks

Comment: @mohammad_1m2: Nicolas' answer is correct, though there may not be enough explanation why. the scheduler doesn't necessarily have to pick the notified thread to run next, it's possible to have an ordering where the notified thread doesn't get to run until after the other consumer has already consumed the list contents and left it empty. any assumptions you make about what the state is after having woken from waiting (during which time the thread relinquished the monitor) are worthless.

Comment: @mohammad_1m2 What you don't understand in my example is the fact that we have only one consumer thread waiting to be notified, the other consumer only waits for the lock on the variable strings. When the producer calls notify, it will release the consumer waiting to be notified but this thread still needs to acquire the lock on the variable strings so if the other consumer gets it first, you will get the error because the consumer that has been notified doesn't re-check the condition first.

Comment: @NathanHughes That's exactly the point, if you have any idea to better formulate my answer, thank you in advance for sharing

Comment: @Tom Sorry Tom, I believe that my answer is not clear enough so I reformulated it a little bit more. Please have a look to the last comments for a better understanding of my answer.